# Python: create (sparse) stacked diagonal block matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to create a matrix with the form

```
M=[
[a1, 0, 0],
[0, b1, 0],
[0, 0, c1],
[a2, 0, 0],
[0, b2, 0],
[0, 0, c2],
[a3, 0, 0],
[0, b3, 0],
[0, 0, c3],
...]
```

where a(i), b(i) and c(i) are [1xp] blocks. The resulting matrix M has the form [3*m x 3*p]. I am given the input data in the form of 3 matrices [m x p]:

```
A = [[a1.T, a2.T, a3.T, ...]].T
B = [[b1.T, b2.T, b3.T, ...]].T
C = [[c1.T, c2.T, c3.T, ...]].T
```

How can I create the matrix M? Ideally it would be sparse using the scipy.sparse library but I am even struggling creating it as a dense matrix using numpy. Is there no way around a loop or at least list comprehension in this case?

Comment: `np.block` is the most general tool for making an array from blocks.  Look at its code for comments about methods.  There are some functions for making arrays from diagonals, but that's for single values, not blocks.  Still the kinds of indexing used might still be extended to another dimension.  `scipy.sparse.block_diag` can make a matrix from blocks.  Look at its code - it combines the `coo` attributes of the blocks into the `coo` inputs for the new matrix, with appropriate adjustments to coordinates.  There's no multidimensional magic here.

Comment: What are the values of m and p?

Comment: @Reinderien m ~ 70.000, p ~20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make it complicated. For your scale, the following executes in less than a second.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from numpy.random import default_rng

rand = default_rng(seed=0)
m = 70_000
p = 20
abc = rand.random((3, m, p))
M_dense = np.zeros((m, 3, 3*p))
for i in range(3):
    M_dense[:, i, i*p:(i+1)*p] = abc[i, ...]
M_sparse = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(M_dense.reshape((-1, 3*p)))
print(M_sparse.shape)
```

```
(210000, 60)
```

Far better, though, is to [construct the sparse matrix directly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix). Note the permuted shape of `abc`.

```py
abc = rand.random((m, 3, p))
data = abc.ravel()
indices = np.tile(np.arange(3*p), m)
indptr = np.arange(0, data.size+1, p)
M_sparse = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))
```

Comment: using tile for the indices is genius! Thank you for your help (=